# How do you create a very long Static TableView using Storyboard?

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, ios5

I need to create a very long Static TableViewController.

The static table has about 5 groups, each group has a few cells, 2-7 depending on the group.

How do I accomplish this when interface builder only allows you to see the actual screen size and nothing more?

Is there a way to scroll within the tableview while in IB? Or perhaps elongating the screen so that I can see all groups and cells at the same time? I mean, the whole point of IB is to visually design your screens, but how can you design a screen that is multiple pages long?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

UPDATE (Dec 26, 2012): I just noticed today that in the current version of Xcode that you can 2 finger scroll on the trackpad through a long static UITableView in a storyboard. So the answer below is no longer needed.

For your viewController in the Attribute inspector on the right set Size to Freeform. Then for the TableView set the height in the Size inspector to as big as you need (like 1000). Design your giant static table to your hearts content. The default settings for the Struts and Springs should take care of resizing the table back to normal dimensions when the app is run.

Comment: That did the trick however it seems I only have that option using an xib file, not in storyboard mode...

Comment: I successfully did the steps in my answer in storyboard this morning.

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to mark this as the 'answer' if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder will now let you scroll within a UITableView using your scroll wheel.

Not ideal for seeing the entire interface at once, but still very helpful.